# How to point foreign_key instead of table_name_id to something like product_id in a belong_to tale in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, foreign-keys

i have 3 tables
Collections, Contributors and ProductContributors

Association of them is as follows
Collection
has_many :product_contributors
has_many :contributors, :through => Product_contributors

Contributor
has_many :product_contributors
has_many :collections, :through => Product_contributors

ProductContributor
belongs_to :collection
belongs_to :contributor

my product_contributor table has columns as
id
product_id (here it should map to collection_id if product_type is collection)
product_type
contributor_id

is there any way i could do this???

I was trying something like this
belongs_to :collection , :foreign_key => :product_id

pls suggest me wat could be the appropriate solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

In product_contributor you shhould have: `belongs_to :product , :polymorphic => true
and in collection: has_many :product_contributors, :as => :product

Comment: I still have a problem when i edit the page. It says "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'product_contributors.track_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `tracks`.* FROM `tracks` INNER JOIN `product_contributors` ON `tracks`.`id` = `product_contributors`.`track_id` WHERE `product_contributors`.`contributor_id` = '026hboqqTQ'   "

Comment: its still looking for track_id instead I have a product_id for it...why is it not taking product_id as track_id or collection_id...

Comment: whenever I try to load ProductContributor url i gets the following error : Expected /app/models/track.rb to define TRACK. I dont understand what m i missing in ma track.rb and what exactly it means by 'define TRACK'. plz help..!!